# How to convert sql query with addition and join to linq

Tags: sql, linq

I have a working sql query that I have been trying to convert to linq for the past couple of days.  I have read several posts both here and on various site, but have not been successful in any of my attempts to convert this to a working linq query.

The parts that I am specifically having problems with deal with the math (adding individual scores to get the total_score value) and getting the values from the Schools table so I can pass them to my view.

Here is the sql query:

```
SELECT bowler_name, school_name, bowler_gm1, bowler_gm2, bowler_gm3, bowler_gm4, bowler_gm5, bowler_gm6, (ISNULL([bowler_gm1],0)+ISNULL([bowler_gm2],0)+ISNULL([bowler_gm3],0)+ISNULL([bowler_gm4],0)+ISNULL([bowler_gm5],0)+ISNULL([bowler_gm6],0)) AS total_score 
FROM Bowlers 
JOIN Schools ON Schools.school_id = Bowlers.school_id 
ORDER BY total_score DESC;
```

Here is as far as I get with the linq query before things start breaking:

```
from s in db.Schools
join b in db.Bowlers on s.school_id equals b.school_id
select b;
```

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should help you on your way.

```
from s in db.Schools
join b in db.Bowlers on s.school_id equals b.school_id
select new {
  bowler_name = b.bowler_name,
  ...
  totalscore = bowler_gm1 + bowler_gm2 + bowler_gm3 ...
};
```

Note it would be much easier to handle nulls if you were to create a BowlerGame table with
GameID as PK, BowlerID as FK to bowler, GameNumber as game number and finally Score as that game's score

Comment: Thanks for the help - I put this together and now am just working on getting the view.  Thanks!